# Merge 2 numpy arrays and replace existing values by field

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I want to merge 2 `numpy` arrays. Existing elements in the first dimension (field `entid`) shall be replaced whereas non existing element shall be appended.

Like `INSERT OR REPLACE` in SQL with an `UNIQUE INDEX` on column `entid`.

I got this example code:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
import numpy

data = [
    (100, 2.),
    (200, 3.)]

dt = numpy.dtype([("entid", numpy.uint32), ("data", numpy.float32)])
data_arr = numpy.array(data, dtype=dt)

data_b = [
    (1000, 5.),
    (100, 10.)
]
data_arr_b = numpy.array(data_b, dtype=dt)
print data_arr
print data_arr_b

print data_arr.dtype

data_new = numpy.concatenate((data_arr, data_arr_b))
print data_new
```

with the following output

```
[(100L, 2.0) (200L, 3.0)]
[(1000L, 5.0) (100L, 10.0)]
[('entid', '<u4'), ('data', '<f4')]

[(100L, 2.0) (200L, 3.0) (1000L, 5.0) (100L, 10.0)]
```

The expected output would be:

```
[(100L, 10.0) (200L, 3.0) (1000L, 5.0)
```

The element with `entid`=100 should be replaced by `data`=10.0 and a new element with `entid`=1000 and `data`=5.0 should have been added.

I searched the internet and this site but does not find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Although it may be possible to do this in `numpy`, it will be awkward.  You really should be using `pandas`, which is designed to do things like this.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> data_a = [
              (100, 2.),
              (200, 3.)]
>>> data_b = [
              (1000, 5.),
              (100, 10.)]
>>> 
>>> df_a = pd.DataFrame(data_a, columns=['entid', 'data'])
>>> df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_b, columns=['entid', 'data'])
>>> 
>>> df_ai = df_a.set_index('entid')
>>> df_bi = df_b.set_index('entid')
>>> 
>>> df_final = df_bi.combine_first(df_ai)
>>> print(df_final)
       data
entid      
100      10
200       3
1000      5
```

Or, if you have more control over the initial format of the data:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> 
>>> data_a = [2., 3.]
>>> data_b = [5., 10.]
>>>
>>> ind_a = [100, 200]
>>> ind_b = [1000, 100]
>>>
>>> ser_a = pd.Series(data_a, index=ind_a)
>>> ser_b = pd.Series(data_b, index=ind_b)
>>> 
>>> ser_final = ser_b.combine_first(ser_a)
>>> 
>>> print(ser_final)
100      10
200       3
1000      5
```